# Solitude Guards do not respawn anymore

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was bored and I tried to go assassin on all of the guards in Solitude and then one day, they didn't respawn anymore. I tried to spawn them via console but it doesn't do the trick they just stand on where I spawned them. I went inside Castle Dour where the city guards slept and only that guy named Istar Cairn-Breaker was sleeping! All other beds were empty. I spawned some in the room and all they did was sit and stand around looking at each other. Any help would be appreciated! CHEERS!

Comment: Try waiting for 10 in-game days.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the 'resurrect' command? Using this command brings any NPC back to life. To do this, open up the command screen. Then click on a dead guard so it will show his model number. Then type resurrect then their model number (i.e. resurrect 10248190). They should come back to life. Hope I helped

Comment: Uhm I didnt have the chance to ressurect them after i wen full ham.

Answer (score 0):

Guards respawn in 3-5 in-game days

Comment: Well they didnt for me.

Comment: In 10 days not 3-5.

Answer (score 0):

Without the guards Solitude is really lonely, with only a few npcs about 9 only. So this is what I did, I downloaded a mod that adds more npcs to cities from the nexus. Another thing to fix the guard problem, I downloaded a dawnguard city guards with the dawnguard trolls and wolves. So the latter replaced solitude guards with Dawnguard soldiers. this is the link for the latter mod http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/60568. Thanks for the help anyway! cheers